# How to show there is a unique coarsest topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a set, let $\{ X_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in J}$ be an indexed family of spaces; and let $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in J}$ be an indexed family of functions $f_\alpha:A\rightarrow X_\alpha$.

Show there is a unique  coarsest topology $T$ on $A$ relative to which each of the functions $f_\alpha$ is continuous.

I'm just really confused about how to begin this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Start with a single $X$ and $f$, what must be included in the topplogy on $A$ to make $f$ continuous?

Comment: Hint2: If $\mathcal V\subseteq\wp(A)$ then the coarsest topology on $A$ that contains $\mathcal V$ as a subcollection is the intersection of all topologies on $A$ that contain $\mathcal V$ as a subcollection.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Would it be open subsets, $V_\alpha$ of X, that $f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$ is open in $X$?

Comment: @drhab Wouldn't the trivial topology be the coarsest topology in this case?

Comment: That is not excluded, but this only if the  indexed functions are continuous wrt to that topology.